# MPMoviePlayerController creating a custom buffer progress bar for streaming movies

Tags: iphone, streaming, progress-bar, buffer, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am streaming a movie to MPMoviePlayerController by simply passing MPMoviePlayerController the URL of the movie file. I am using my own custom controls and would like to create a progress bar to see how much of the video has been buffered (like in YouTube) . But there doesn't seem to be any available data
to create this. Does anyone know how to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to iOS 5.x the playableDuration did the job.  But since iOS 5 this property seem to always return zero.  Give it a try and please let me know if it does work for you.